# self behavior in Rust

Tags: rust

I want to draw attention to the `self` keyword.

This code compiles fine:

```
let color_code = self.color_code;
self.buffer.chars[row][col].write(ScreenChar {
    ascii_character: byte,
    color_code,
});
```

With my knowledge of Java's *this* keyword, I'm urged to think of the `self` substitution **wrongly** as:

```
self.buffer.chars[row][col].write(ScreenChar {
    ascii_character: byte,
    self.color_code: self.color_code,
});
```

i.e. I've removed the *let color_code* and used *self.color_code: self.color_code*.

I'm curious as to why my intuition is wrong with regards to Rust.

Comment: Second one shuld be: `color_code: self.color_code` without `self` on the left side.

Comment: `self.color_code: foo` is nonsensical because the double-colon makes this the name of a field in `ScreenChar` but no `foo.bar` can't be such an ident. `color_code: self.color_code` should work just fine.

Comment: My questions is: why shouldn't `self.color_code :self.color_code` work? Isn't it what that `let color_code = self.color_code;` doing in the first place?

Answer (score 1):

`let color_code = self.color_code` does not modify `self.color_code`. In this regard it is very different from Java's implied `this.`.

What it does instead is creating a new scope-local variable `color_code` that is initialized with `self.color_code`.

When you create/initialize a struct (in your case `ScreenChar`), then rust expects you to initialize the members in a certain way. Excerpt here:

- `field: value`: In this case, rust assumes `field` is the name of a member of the struct, but `self.color_code` is not the name of a member of `ScreenChar` (`color_code` is). Thus, you probably only want `color_code: self.color_code`.
- `field`: In this case rust assumes `field` is the name of a member of the struct and also requires a variable of the same name in scope.

For more information, you can have a look at https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/ch05-01-defining-structs.html#defining-and-instantiating-structs.

Comment: I'm familiar with Structs. Syntax of the struct is another issue (which throws me off and I've created a bug report here: https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/71028) . My question is very clear: Why shouldn't `self.color_code :self.color_code` work? Isn't it what that `let color_code = self.color_code;` doing in the first place?

Comment: @Jerry `let` bindings are not textual substitutions. Would you expect `let color_code = foo(); println!("{} {}", color_code, color_code)` to do the same thing as `println!("{} {}", foo(), foo())`?

Comment: @Jerry No, it is not what `let color_code = self.color_code` does. `let color_code = self.color_code` creates a new scope-local variable `color_code` that is initialized with `self.color_code`.

Comment: @trentcl and @phimuemue : both your answers make sense. trentcl answer helped me think in the right direction. Apparently *the bindings for struct-field initialization is stronger than the binding with `let` initialization*. Thanks for helping me arrive at this understanding.